# How to change keys in Fedora 28 (VMWare issue?)

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, vmware-fusion

I'm using

- Fedora 28 with KDE
- MacOS High Sierra on a MacBook Pro with a german keyboard
- VMWare Fusion 8.5.9
- german keyboard layout

Whichever keyboard layout I choose in the KDE settings, the key for `<`/`>` and `^`/`°` are exchanged. I don't the reason and I don't know how to fix it. Any ideas? All other keys seems to work as expected.

Comment: Hass something to do with the german keyboard layout. Found some info [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apple_Keyboard#.3C_and_.3E_have_changed_place_with_.5E_and_.C2.B0_.28or_.40_and_.23.2C_or_.60_and_.7E.29)

Comment: I finally solved it by using another keyboard profile in the fusion settings. There can be keys swapped. However in my case this is not possible with a new profile. For some reason I can do this only with an existing profile that has _language specific_ entries. They already there, but in a new profile I cannot add _language specific_ key swappings. Also the checkbox to activate them is disabled there. I don't know why.